# Android connect/disconnect a specific Bluetooth device (or BT profile) from command line

Tags: android, shell, command-line, bluetooth, chromecast

There are already several topics for *enabling/disabling Bluetooth via command line* on an Android device. But these don't help me for my particular case, where the Android device is a **Chromecast 4K with Bluetooth.** That is, if I entirely disable Bluetooth on Chromecast – usually to disconnect the BT headset –, the Bluetooth remote will get disconnected as well!

So, what I need is a shell command sequence (usable for *Button Mapper*) which either

1. disconnects/reconnects just a particular Bluetooth device (preferable by friendly name, but BT Address is also OK) or
2. disable/enable just a certain profile (**A2DP** in our case), in order to leave remote control functionality untouched.

Obviously I'd avoid rooting, but as a desperate solution I can root my Chromecast device, if there is no other way.

Comment: With `bluetoothctl` you can do this.

Comment: Does `bluetoothctl` work on Android as well? Some sources would suggest it doesn't.

Comment: @Risto , if so, how to invoke it from Termux? Does it need some prerequisites?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I somehow had Linux/BlueZ in my mind. I'm not familiar with the Fluoride Bluetooth stack.